# Insert into a BigQuery table the result of ML.EVALUATE does not actually insert

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-insert

I am trying to follow along [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/continuous-model-evaluation-bigquery-ml-stored-procedures-and-cloud-scheduler) tutorial about continuous evaluation that uses BigQuery.

I have created a table metrics with the command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE airlines_arrival_delay.metrics AS (   SELECT
    CURRENT_TIME() as timestamp, 
      "linreg" AS modelname,
      *

    FROM
      ML.EVALUATE(MODEL airlines_arrival_delay.linreg,
        (SELECT * FROM airlines_arrival_delay.test)
      )   LIMIT 0 )
```

Unlike the tutorial, I put all resources (model, table, etc) under the same dataset called `airlines_arrival_delay`.

I also imported a train and test csv, and created a linear regressor with `CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL`.

I am now trying to evaluate the linear regressor on the test csv and insert the evaluation numbers to the table metrics. Here is the SQL command I use for this:

```
INSERT `airlines_arrival_delay.metrics` (`timestamp`,`modelname`, `mean_absolute_error`,    `mean_squared_error`,   `mean_squared_log_error`, `median_absolute_error`,  `r2_score`, `explained_variance`)
  SELECT
    CURRENT_TIME() as timestamp, 
    "linreg" AS modelname,
    *
  FROM
    ML.EVALUATE(MODEL airlines_arrival_delay.linreg,
      (SELECT * FROM airlines_arrival_delay.test_preprocessed)
    )
```

The command runs successfully, and I even have an info under the tab "Results" that says that a row has been appended to the table metrics (see figure below)

[image: figure]

Now when I click on the button "Go to table" or go to the table metrics by clicking on it under my dataset `airlines_arrival_delay`, I see that the table is empty:

[image: fig2]

How can I modify the last command above to make the insert effective ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really thought it was an error in my SQL commands, but it turns out it's not the problem. I refreshed the webpage and then saw all the rows in the table `metrics`. Clicking on the table only seems not to be enough.

Comment: if the issue doesn't seem to repro, maybe consider to close the question.